# Alphabetically sorting and filtering a combo box that's being auto filled using sheet names

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, combobox, filtering

The target here is to have a dropdown box on the front page of a 50+ sheet Excel workbook that auto fills with each sheet name, and the list being sorted alphabetically (ascending) and filtering out certain entries.

So far I've got this (which works, from here [How to make a drop-down list for worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601296/vba-excel-drop-down-list-for-worksheets)) to do the auto fill:

```
    Private Sub workbook_open()
    Dim LSheets As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim OCmbBox As MSForms.ComboBox
    Set OCmbBox = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).CmbSheet
    OCmbBox.Clear
    For Each LSheets In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    OCmbBox.AddItem LSheets.Name
    Next LSheets
    End Sub
```

As mentioned above, the challenge now is to sort that list alphabetically, and filter out a few entries. Specifically the front page sheet itself, and any sheet that starts with the word 'BETA'

Elsewhere on here I'd found 2 potential options for the sorting, but I'm hitting a block on how to combine that in with what I've already got.

[Sort Combobox VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543399/sort-combobox-vba)

As for the filtering, I was looking at a SELECT CASE type arrangement, but couldn't see how to flag a negative as it were.

Something a little like this:

```
    Private Sub workbook_open()
    Dim LSheets As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim OCmbBox As MSForms.ComboBox
    Set OCmbBox = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).CmbSheet
    OCmbBox.Clear
    For Each LSheets In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If UCase(Left(LSheets.Name, 4)) IS NOT "BETA": OCmbBox.AddItem LSheets.Name
        Else Next Lsheets
    End Sub
```

But you don't even want to know the hideous errors that gave me! For a start, there isn't an IS NOT, and != didn't get me anywhere either (yeah, I've not really looked at anything even remotely resembling code since Cyrix were still building CPU's...)

Any help/guidance the community here can provide would be gratefully received.

Cheers.

Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, using a temp sheet to sort, then delete the temp sheet after.  This will also ignore sheets whose names start with "BETA" as well as the first sheet in the workbook:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arrSheets As Variant
    Dim strSheets As String
    Dim lNumSheets As Long
    Dim cboSheets As MSForms.ComboBox

    Set cboSheets = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).CmbSheet
    cboSheets.Clear

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Index > 1 And Not ws.Name Like "BETA*" Then
            lNumSheets = lNumSheets + 1
            strSheets = strSheets & ":" & ws.Name
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Sheets.Add.Range("A1").Resize(lNumSheets)
        .Value = Application.Transpose(Split(Mid(strSheets, 2), ":"))
        .Sort .Cells, xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        arrSheets = .Value
        .Worksheet.Delete
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    cboSheets.List = arrSheets

End Sub
```

Comment: You sir, are an unadulterated legend. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can make another subprocedure or function to sort:

```
Sub SortWorksheets()

Dim N As Integer
Dim M As Integer
Dim FirstWSToSort As Integer
Dim LastWSToSort As Integer
Dim SortDescending As Boolean

SortDescending = False

If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count = 1 Then
    FirstWSToSort = 2
    LastWSToSort = Worksheets.Count
Else
    With ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        For N = 2 To .Count
            If .Item(N - 1).Index <> .Item(N).Index - 1 Then
                MsgBox "You cannot sort non-adjacent sheets"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next N
        FirstWSToSort = .Item(1).Index
        LastWSToSort = .Item(.Count).Index
     End With
End If

For M = FirstWSToSort To LastWSToSort
    For N = M To LastWSToSort
      If left(UCase(Worksheets(N).Name,4) = "BETA"
      Else
        If SortDescending = True Then
            If UCase(Worksheets(N).Name) > UCase(Worksheets(M).Name) Then
                Worksheets(N).Move before:=Worksheets(M)
            End If
        Else
            If UCase(Worksheets(N).Name) < UCase(Worksheets(M).Name) Then
               Worksheets(N).Move before:=Worksheets(M)
            End If
        End If
      End If
     Next N
Next M

End Sub
```

`FirstWSToSort` you can change - I set it to 2 because you said you didn't want the title screen to be included.

You can sort descending by changing `SortDescending` to true.

You can include or remove more conditions in the If statement within the N and M loops:

```
If left(UCase(Worksheets(N).Name,4) = "BETA"
```

Comment: So how/where is the best place/way to call that procedure? From within the initial workbook_open() that's creating the list? Bearing in mind that at the moment it's placed in the (Code) section of ThisWorkbook, rather than on a specific sheet.

Comment: Also, one of your lines there is giving me a compile error. 'Expected: list separator or )'  it's happening at the "If left (UCase(Worksheets(N).Name,4) = "BETA" line within the For section. It looks like there's a bracket missing, but I can't seem to figure out where it should go as it still breaks on me,.

Answer (score 0):

I like the select case idea for ignoring worksheets. Also it's perhaps easiest to put the valid worksheets into an array first, then sort the array, and then loop through it to add the items to the combobox

Ex.

```
Private Sub workbook_open()
    Dim lsheets As Worksheet
    Dim validSheets() As Worksheet
    ReDim validSheets(0)

    For Each lsheets In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Select Case UCase(Left(lsheets.name, 4))
            Case "BETA":
                'sheet's name is beta
                MsgBox "beta"
            Case Else
                'sheet's name is not beta
                'put code to add sheet to combobox here
                MsgBox "not beta"
                'if the last item in the array is used then increase array size
                If Not validSheets(UBound(validSheets)) Is Nothing Then
                    ReDim Preserve validSheets(0 To UBound(validSheets) + 1)
                End If
                'add valid sheet to last place in array
                Set validSheets(UBound(validSheets)) = lsheets
        End Select
    Next lsheets

    'now sort the array of valid sheets
    exampleFunctionSort validSheets

    'now add the array of valid sheets in order
    Dim index As Integer
    For index = LBound(validSheets) To UBound(validSheets)
        'add sheet here
    Next index
End Sub

'place array sort code here
Private Function exampleFunctionSort(arr As Variant)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Woo Hoo! My time to shine. (I like brevity.)

```
Private Sub workbook_open()
Dim LSheets As Excel.Worksheet
Dim OCmbBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Set OCmbBox = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).CmbSheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
OCmbBox.Clear

With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "BETA" Then .Add sht.Name
    Next
    .Sort
    OCmbBox.List = Application.Transpose(.toarray())
End With
```

End Sub